# Windows 7 doesn't "see" my graphics card

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, ati-mobility-radeon

Alright, this is all very peculiar but I'll try to include everything. But first, my machine configuration. I'm running on an HP G62-B75EV Notebook with a switchable graphics configuration and the following specs:

- CPU: Intel Core i5 M460 @ 2.5 GHz (Dual Core)
- RAM: 4 GB
- HDD: 500 GB
- GPU: Intel HD Graphics Integrated Chipset + Mobility Radeon HD5470 (1GB VRAM?)
- OS: Windows 7 64 bit

My problem is that presently, the computer only seems to see the on-board card. This all must have started when I tried installing Leshcat's custom UnifL drivers, but when I rolled back, everything was OK until a few days ago. Under Device Manager, there's only the Intel HD Graphics card and no sign of the dedicated one. No, it isn't listed in Other Devices or as a VGA-Compatible adapter. What's strange is that I can hook up another screen -which I don't think an onboard would support- and when I uninstall the HD Graphics driver either from the Device Manager or with Device Driver Uninstaller (which I believe is the culprit for all this), Windows searches and successfully detects both cards, installing the predefined drivers (not from Windows Update). Now, if I try to install the HP ATI drivers, after the reboot I get a BSOD reporting that a system file called atikmpag.sys is causing the problem. I went into Safe Mode and tried expanding the atikmpag.sy_ file from AMD's Support folder. What this does is that my computer does boot into normal mode, but both cards' drivers display an exclamation mark saying that there's no digital signature. When this happens, the computer obviously uses the default drivers, as I can only max out to 1024x768 resolution.

I don't know what else to do; I've tried almost everything. I'm certain that this is a software issue, as the computer can detect the card when I uninstall the HD Graphics driver (see my methods above) and honestly, I can't believe that it just decided to die on me after 3 years, no damage or spillage and without at least some warning signs like artifacts or random crashes - up until 2 weeks ago I was playing BF3 with decent FPS. Also, service is currently not an option and I'd like to fix the problem myself.

Comment: I do, it's Windows 7. And as far as I understand, they aren't from Windows Update. I even let them install after closing my router to make sure, and they still go ahead. They are probably arbitrary drivers that need to be installed in order to install the correct ones.

Comment: I doubt you would have changed it but there is a setting in the BIOS to enable/disable switchable graphics. Ensure that both are enabled here

Comment: -which I don't think an onboard would support- Your assumption is very wrong.

Comment: Have you tried backing everything up and restoring the computer to factory settings?

Comment: Moved from comments on answer likely to be deleted because it's a comment:  PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0046&SUBSYS_143A103C&REV_02 PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0046&SUBSYS_143A103C PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0046&CC_030000 PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0046&CC_0300 These are from the integrated chip. Right now, the ATI doesn't show up at all so I can't give you its identifiers. But I do recall messing with Device Manager when both cards showed up, and it stated that the ATI was on "PCI port 1", which tells me that the card isn't broken.

Comment: EDIT: Managed to find the ATI identifiers: PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_68E0&SUBSYS_143A103C&REV_00 PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_68E0&SUBSYS_143A103C PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_68E0&CC_030000 PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_68E0&CC_0300

Comment: If this question is still open, please edit these comments into the question.  If the problem has been overtaken by events, please update the status and whether you still need a solution.  If you solved the problem, consider posting an answer with your solution.